# How to display image inside image tag using Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, image, ng-file-upload

I need some help.i need to display multiple image and when also user will select the image it will push into array.I am explaining my code below.

```
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12" ng-repeat="mul in mulImage">
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Image{{$index+1}}:</span>
<div>
<div ng-class="{'myError': billdata.upload_{{$index}}.$touched && billdata.upload_{{$index}}.$invalid }">
 <input type="file" class="filestyle form-control" data-size="lg" name="upload_{{$index}}" id="bannerimage_{{$index}}"  ng-model="mul.image" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB" ngf-min-height="400" ngf-resize="{width: 400, height:400}"  ngf-select="onFileSelect1('upload_{{$index}}',mul.image);">
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
 <input type="text" id="hidn_{{$index}}" ng-model="attach_{{$index}}" style="display:none" />
 </div>
 </div>
<span class="input-group-btn" ng-show="mulImage.length>0">
 <img ngf-thumbnail="mul.image" name="pro" border="0" style="width:32px; height:32px; border:#808080 1px solid;">
 <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="plus" id="plus" value="+" ng-click="addNewImageRow(mulImage);" ng-show="$last"> <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="minus" id="minus" value="-"  ng-show="mulImage.length>1" ng-click="deleteNewImageRow(mulImage,$index);">

 </span>
</div>

 </div>
```

Here i am using `ng-file-upload` to upload the multiple image  by `plus` button.When user will select the image from local drive the the images are displaying.But there is an additional case i have some image name i need to display those first and if user will select more it can be also possible.

```
 $scope.mulImage=[];
   $scope.mulImage.push({'image':null});
   $scope.addNewImageRow=function(mulImage){
       mulImage.push({'image':null});
   }
   $scope.deleteNewImageRow=function(mulImage,index){
       mulImage.splice(index,1);
       console.log('file',$scope.mulImage[0]['image'].name);
   }
```

The above is my controller side code.

```
var arr=["10lx18i3ciyhkt9_de021b24.jpg", "ajqgis4v1wi2j4i_a6d6c48a.jpg", "7pxknunjop9cnmi_silu nana.jpg"]
```

Suppose i have the above images before.When the page will refresh  the first 3 images will display to user like `upload/10lx18i3ciyhkt9_de021b24.jpg` and 3 image row also will create.if user wants to add/delete it can be also possible.Please help me.

Comment: So what the issue is here?

Comment: Kindly review this answer on this URL:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/34505499/366884